Laravel 11 - disable all of the "Set-Cookie" headers? (XCSRF + Laravel Session)
I have an issue with Laravel 11.x, that now you no longer have the middlewares in the Kernel file, thus I don't see a way to entirely remove the session and xcsrf set-cookie headers.
The issue I'm facing is that our CDN won't cache responses that have Set-Cookie, as they are cache penetrating.
I've tried adding this, but it didn't help:
$middleware->validateCsrfTokens(
            except: ['*']
        );

I've also tried writing my own middleware (e.g. RemoveThoseCookies::class), and inside I've tried the following:
$response = $next($request);
        $response->headers->remove('Set-Cookie');
        return $response
            ->withoutCookie('laravel_session')
            ->withoutCookie('XSRF-TOKEN');

That only changed the cookie to "removed", but the set-cookie headers are still there.
Note that I've prepended the middleware, thus it should have been the last one on the way out, but I'm not sure.
Appreciate your assistance!

How about adding the $middleware->removeFromGroup() inside the withMiddleware()

That's easy. Just remove the relevant middleware classes (StartSession::class, ShareErrorsFromSession::class and ValidateCsrfToken::class) from the stack in bootstrap/app.php:
use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Exceptions;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Configuration\Middleware;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidateCsrfToken;
use Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession;
use Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession;

return Application::configure(basePath: dirname(__DIR__))
    ->withRouting(
        web: __DIR__ . '/../routes/web.php',
        commands: __DIR__ . '/../routes/console.php',
        health: '/up',
    )->withMiddleware(function (Middleware $middleware) {
        $middleware->web(remove: [
            StartSession::class,
            ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
            ValidateCsrfToken::class,
        ]);
    })->withExceptions(function (Exceptions $exceptions) {
        //
    })->create();

